# Running Word Count or Pig Script on a Directory to produce result in separate files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Hadoop/Pig.

I have a directory which has several files. Now I need to run a word count on those. I can use the Hadoop sample example wordcount and run it on the directory to get the output, but the output will be in a single file. What should I do if I want the output of each file should be in a different file? 
I can use Pig too. And give the directory as input to pig. However how can I read the file names inside the Directory and then give it to the LOAD? 
What I meant is:
Say I have a directory Test which has 5 files test1, test2, test3, test4, test5. Now I want the word count of each file separately in a separate file. I know I can provide individual names and do it, but that would take a lot of time. 
Is it possible that I can read filenames from the directory and provide them as input to LOAD of pig?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Pig version 0.10.0 or later, you can take advantage of a combination of [source tagging](http://hadoopified.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/pigstorage-options-schema-and-source-tagging/) and [MultiStorage](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html) to keep track of the files.

For example, if you had an input directory `pigin` with files and content as the following:

```
pigin
|-test1 => "hello"
|-test2 => "world"
|-test3 => "Apache"
|-test4 => "Hadoop"
|-test5 => "Pig"
```

The following script will read each script and write the contents of each file to a different directory.

```
%declare inputPath 'pigin'
%declare outputPath 'pigout'

-- Define MultiStorage to write output to different directories based on the
-- first element in the tuple
define MultiStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('$outputPath','0');

-- Load the input files, prepending each tuple with the file name
A = load '$inputPath' using PigStorage(',', '-tagsource');

-- Write output to different directories
store A into '$outputPath' using MultiStorage();
```

The above script will create an output directory tree that looks like the following:

```
pigout
|-test1
| `-test1-0 => "test1   hello"
|-test2
| `-test2-0 => "test2   world"
|-test3
| `-test3-0 => "test3   Apache"
|-test4
| `-test4-0 => "test4   Hadoop"
|-test5
| `-test5-0 => "test5   Pig"
```

The `-0` at the end of the filenames correspond to the reducers that produced the output. If you have more than one reducer, you may see more than one file per directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the PigStorage code to add the file name to the tuple, see [Code Sample](https://cwiki.apache.org/PIG/faq.html) look for question "Q: I load data from a directory which contains different file. How do I find out where the data comes from?". For the output you could do similar extension of the PigStorage to write into different output files.

Comment: Thanks alexeipab. The link looks interesting.
However, how would using Embedded Pig in Java work here? Any thoughts.